# What does it mean that message boxes are being suppressed in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Here's a page from documentation: [SuppressibleMsgBox](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_suppressiblemsgbox.htm).

What does it mean *If message boxes are being suppressed...*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a link to the explanation right after the  part you have quoted:

> If message boxes are being suppressed (see [Setup Command Line Parameters](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline)), `Default` is returned.

In the link, there's [`/SUPPRESSMSGBOXES` commandline parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline&anchor=SUPPRESSMSGBOXES) documented:

> Instructs Setup to suppress message boxes. Only has an effect when combined with '/SILENT' or '/VERYSILENT'.

So normally, the `SuppressibleMsgBox` behaves as the [`MsgBox`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_msgbox). But if you run the installer with the `/SUPPRESSMSGBOXES` parameter, the `SuppressibleMsgBox` does nothing, only silently returns the value of the `Default` parameter.

A practical example of use of the function:

```pascal
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  Dir: string;
  Msg: string;
begin
  Result := True;
  if CurPageID = wpSelectDir then
  begin
    Dir := WizardForm.DirEdit.Text;
    if Pos(' ', Dir) > 0 then
    begin
      Msg :=
        'It is not recommended to install the application to a path with spaces. '
        + 'Do you want to continue anyway?';
      if SuppressibleMsgBox(Msg, mbInformation, MB_YESNO, IDYES) = IDNO then
      begin
        Result := False;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

In an interactive installation, the installer will warn, if the user tries to install to a path with spaces. But if you are automating a silent installation with `/SILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES`, the installer will proceed.

It's good idea to use `SuppressibleMsgBox` whenever you do not want that particular message to break silent installation. So for most cases.